# Using replace function in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to use replace function to replace "('", "'" and "')" from the below string -

```
String foo = "('UK', 'IT', 'DE')";
```

I am trying to use the below code in order to do this operation -

```
(foo.contains("('")?foo.replaceAll("('", ""):foo.replace("'",""))?foo.replaceAll("')",""):foo
```

but its failing as -

> `java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed group near index 2`

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: `replaceAll` request a regular expression, and `'('` has special meaning in there; use plain `replace()` (which you already are partially using)

Comment: Just use replace() instead of replaceAll().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`replaceAll` takes a [*regular expression*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/) as its search pattern. Since `(` is a special character in regular expressions, it need to be escaped: `'\\('`. Furthermore, there’s no need for the `contains` test:

```
final String bar = foo.replaceAll("\\('", "") …
```

Lastly, you can combine all your replacements into one regular expression:

```
final String bar = foo.replaceAll("\\(?'([^']*)'\\)?", "$1");
// Output: UK, IT, DE
```

This will replace each occurrence of a single-quoted part inside your string with its content without the quotes, and it will allow (and discard) surrounding opening and closing parentheses.

Comment: What about "'"?

Comment: @user85421 Yeah I guess. But I had to explain *why* OP’s code didn’t work, and then use that as the stepping stone for the ultimate, complete solution.

Comment: The OP didn't mean to use a regex, just a simple replace(). Using a regex here is just overkill.

Comment: @Olivier Sure, they didn’t *intend to* use regular expressions, but they accidentally did, and regex are unavoidable for general string processing in Java (for example, you can’t replace just a single instance using `replace`), so it’s important to know how to use them. I also disagree that using regex here is overkill. Without regex, you’d have to call `replace` repeatedly with different substrings. My method (a) allows using a single call, and (b) more clearly communicates what kind of input is expected.

Answer (score 0):

`foo.replaceAll("[(')]", "")` will make the work )

Answer (score 0):

As other answer(s) and the error message point out, `replaceAll()` deals with regular expressions, where the opening parenthesis `(` has special meaning. Some characters have special meaning even in the replacement argument for the same reason.

If you want to be absolutely sure that your strings are going to behave as strings, there are two built-in "quote" methods (both are `static`) for "neutralizing" patterns:

- [`Pattern.quote()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String)) for wrapping the replacee pattern
- [`Matcher.quoteReplacement()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement(java.lang.String)) for wrapping the replacement

Example code attempting to `replaceAll()` two `(` to `$` symbols:

```
System.out.println("Naive:");
try {
    System.out.println("(("
            .replaceAll("(", "$"));
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);
}
System.out.println("\nPattern.quote:");
try {
    System.out.println("q: "+Pattern.quote("("));
    System.out.println("(("
            .replaceAll(Pattern.quote("("), "$"));
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);
}
System.out.println("\nPattern.quote+Matcher.quoteReplacement:");
try {
    System.out.println("q: "+Pattern.quote("("));
    System.out.println("qR: "+Matcher.quoteReplacement("$"));
    System.out.println("(("
            .replaceAll(Pattern.quote("("), Matcher.quoteReplacement("$")));
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);
}
```

Output:

> ```
> Naive:
> java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed group near index 1
> (
>
> Pattern.quote:
> q: \Q(\E
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal group reference: group index is missing
>
> Pattern.quote+Matcher.quoteReplacement:
> q: \Q(\E
> qR: \$
> $$
> ```

Of course by the time one knows about these methods, they have long got accustomed to escape the special characters manually.